# Possibility to host and serve Mobile apps from my own repo ?

Tags: android, iphone, deployment, mobile, rhomobile

I saw sites like rhogallery (http://rhohub.com/), testflightapp.com helping developers to test their app before it goes for app store or marketplace.

I would like to know whether Apple/Android allows (with legal permission) us to setup our own Repo like this?

Our need is to host and serve mobile apps while we dont want that to be made publically available on App store/Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

Old question now but would be useful for somebody searching for this. From what I know, you can install third part apps from places other than the app stores but by enabling that particular setting from your phone